# Leaflet React get map instance in functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-v3

I want to have a button outside the map that changes the view to another coordinates.

Is there any way to get mapContainer instance to call their functions? Or how can I implement that function?

I tried to get it by using ref, but it's not working.
Here is my current code

```
const zoom = 13;

function Map({ regionCoord, regionName }) {

    const mapRef = useRef();

    function handleFlyToClick() {
      // This don't work
      // const map = mapRef.current.leafletElement 
      // map.flyTo(regionCoord, zoom)
    }

 return (   
        <React.Fragment>
            <Grid container >
                <Grid item xs={10}>
                    {regionCoord && <MapContainer
                        ref={mapRef}                     
                        center={[50,50]} 
                        zoom={zoom}                    
                        >
                        <TileLayer
                            attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                        />            
   
                        <Marker position={regionCoord}>
                          <Popup>{regionName}</Popup>
                        </Marker>        
                    </MapContainer>}                               
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={2}>
                    <button onClick={handleFlyToClick}>Fly To</button>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </React.Fragment>  
    )
    
}

export default Map
```

I'm using react-leaflet v3

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to use a component which will include your button inside. To take the map instance use `whenCreated` prop of `MapContainer`. I think `mapRef` is not valid anymore with the latest version.

MapContainer:

```
 const [map, setMap] = useState(null);

 <MapContainer
      center={[50, 50]}
      zoom={zoom}
      style={{ height: "90vh" }}
      whenCreated={setMap}
  >
...

</MapContainer>
<FlyToButton />  // use the button here outside of the MapContainer

....
```

Create the component with the button and its event

```
function FlyToButton() {
  const onClick = () => map.flyTo(regionCoord, zoom);
    
  return <button onClick={onClick}>Add marker on click</button>;
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-v3x-get-map-instance-in-functional-component-hn0x4?file=/src/Map.jsx:1198-1224)

Comment: Struggeld to find how to get the instace of the map (whenCreated={setMap}) saved my life. Thanks

Comment: Wish this was in the documentation!

Comment: whenCreated does not appear to exist in react-leaflet 4.x

Comment: This answer was for react-leaflet v.3.x. It is clearly mentioned in the question.

Comment: @kboul would you not then consider it a duplicate if someone posted the same exact question for 4.x?

Comment: It is not since the api changes all the time so it requires a different answer every time, that's the reason I guess  for making different tags for react-leaflet.

Comment: Could be wrong but ```whenReady={setMap}```  seems to be working for me

Answer (score 10):

`whenCreated` doesn't exist anymore on 4.0 but there is `ref` :

MapContainer:

```
const [map, setMap] = useState<Map|null>(null);

 <MapContainer
      center={[50, 50]}
      zoom={zoom}
      style={{ height: "90vh" }}
      ref={setMap}
  >
   <div> 
     ... do whatever you want with `map`
   </div
</MapContainer>
```

Comment: correct answer as of latest version of react leaflet

Answer (score 2):

**Works for both 3.x and 4.x:**

Another method is to use the [`useMap`](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map/#usemap) hook, which exists in 3.x and 4.x. In order to use it in the parent component, you just need to add a child component, e.g. `MapController` below.

```
const MapController = () => {
  const map = useMap();

  // do something with map, in a useEffect hook, for example.

  return <></>;
};

 <MapContainer
      center={[50, 50]}
      zoom={zoom}
      style={{ height: "90vh" }}
  >
   <MapController />
   <div> 
     ... do whatever you want with `map`
   </div
</MapContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to access the map element(from the map component which is the container not MapContainer), this is a very simple example:

```
export default function MapComponent() {
    const [mapCenter,setMapCenter] = useState([13.1538432,30.2154278])
    let [zoom,setZoomLevel] = useState(15)
    let [tile,setTile] = useState('https://tiles.stadiamaps.com/tiles/alidade_smooth_dark/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png')
    
    let mapRef = useRef();

    const fly=()=>{
        mapRef.current.leafletElement.flyTo([14,30],15)
    }

    return (
    <>
        <button onClick={fly}>Click</button>
        <Map center={mapCenter} zoom={zoom} ref={mapRef} style={{width:'100%',height:'100%'}}>
            <TileLayer url={tile}/>
        </Map>
    </>  
    )
}
```

Comment: i saw @kboul answer after i posted this, note i'm using react-leaflet 2.8.0.

Comment: This does not work on Leaflet 3.0 anymore. The way is as described by the accepted answer here, using <MapContainer
      center={[50, 50]}
      zoom={zoom}
      style={{ height: "90vh" }}
      whenCreated={setMap}
  >