# Using fitBounds in React-Leaflet

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

I have two issues, both of which I have managed to get working in another app using plain Leaflet with Vanilla JS/jquery but I am having issues using React Leaflet.

The first is how to obtain a similar result as to calling .getBounds() (finding a bounding box?) so that I can pass these onto .fitBounds.

The second is how to use .fitBounds in React-Leaflet. I've looked pretty extensively and can find similar solutions but not any that seem to work for mine.

I've successfully obtained geoJson objects/coordinates returned from my node.js backend, and they definitely work as I'm managing to create a geoJson layer each time they are received. Any help/ideas massively appreciated!

n.b. I have also seen other examples using the useMap() hook but cannot seem to get this to work...

Thanks in advance.

```
    import React, { createRef } from 'react';
    import { MapContainer, TileLayer, GeoJSON } from "react-leaflet";
    import axios from 'axios';
    
    import Card1 from '../Card/card';
    
    
    class MyMap extends React.Component{
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                location: '',
                latitude: 52.5,
                longitude: 0.12,
                geoJson: null,
            }
            this.searchLocation = this.searchLocation.bind(this);
            this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
            this.mapRef = createRef();
          }
          
          searchLocation = async (location) => {
            this.setState({
              location: location})
            const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/location', { params: {location} })
            if (response.status !== 200){
                throw Error(response.message)
            } else {
                this.setState({ geoJson: response.data.geoJson, key: response.data.key })
            }
          }
    
          countryStyle = {
              fillColor: 'red'
          };
          
           
        render(){    
    
            const ReturnGeoJson = () => {
//DOES NOT WORK
            // let map = this.mapRef
            // // const layer = customAreaRef.current.leafletElement
            // if(this.state.geoJson){
            //   let bounds = this.state.geoJson.getBounds();
            //   map.fitBounds(bounds, {
            //     animate: true
            //   })
            // }
      
              return this.state.geoJson && (
                <GeoJSON data={this.state.geoJson} key={this.state.key}
                />
              )
          }
    
            return(
            <div>
          <MapContainer zoomControl={false} center={[this.state.latitude, this.state.longitude]} zoom={5.5}>
                <Card1 searchLocation={this.searchLocation} location={this.state.location}/>
                <TileLayer
                url="<MAP URL GOES HERE>" 
                attribution='<MAP ATTR GOES HERE>'
                />
                
    
    
                {ReturnGeoJson()}
               
            </MapContainer>
            </div>
            
                        
            )
        }
    }
    
    export default MyMap;
```

Comment: Inside `ReturnGeoJson`, is `this.mapRef` what you think it is?  Is `this.state.geoJson.getBounds` what you think it is?  These are the things I would look at when debugging.

Comment: Many thanks @SethLutske - in the last half hour I found a solution. My issue is that I was not able to get an instance of my map - according to [another post on said issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65394203/leaflet-react-get-map-instance-in-functional-component), mapRef is no longer valid. I ended up changing to a functional component instead, and using  `const [map, setMap] = useState(null);`, along with `<MapContainer id="mapContainer" zoomControl={false} center={[51.5074, .1278]} zoom={7.5} whenCreated={setMap}>`. I hope this helps someone else!