# React-Leaflet, Change zoom and position according to object array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-v3

So this is my MapComponent, I have added logic wherein whatever is inputted in the search bar it will display those school that is in an array, what I wanna do is add some zoom and change position effect whenever the button is clicked `<button type="button" onClick={() => updateMapCenterZoom(value.position, 15)}>` but still it doesn't work with setView or any other tips

```
 const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [position, setPosition] = useState([14.389786, 121.047566]);
  const [mapZoom, setMapZoom] = useState(13);

  const filteredSchools = schoolData.filter((val) => {
    if (query === "") {
      return val;
    } else {
      return (
        val.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()) ||
        val.type.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())
      );
    }
  });

  const updateMapCenterZoom = (newCenter, newZoom) => {
    setPosition(newCenter);
    setMapZoom(newZoom);
    
  };
```

and this is where it returns from MapComponent(React Component)

```
<MapContainer preferCanvas center={position} zoom={mapZoom} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
            <TileLayer
              attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
              url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
             {filteredSchools.map((value, key) => (
              <Marker
                key={value.id}
                position={value.position}
                eventHandlers={{ click: (e) => handleMarkerClick(e, value) }}>
                  <Popup>{value.name}</Popup>
                </Marker>
                
                ))}
                
          </MapContainer>
```

and outside this I have this function where in it creates and automates the suggestion according to the search query
NOTE: the `<MapContainer />` and the `<div id='school-container'/>` tags are both inside the return statement of MapComponent

```
<div id="school-container">
              {filteredSchools.map((value, key) => (
                <div key={key}>
                  <div className="border border-white-500 min-w-[10pc] w-[25pc] max-w-[30pc] text-white p-3 flex flex-row items-center hover:bg-amber-600">
                    <Link to={value.link}>
                      <img src={value.image} alt="logo" className="w-20 l-10 m-2" />
                      <div className="flex flex-col space-y-3 xs:text-xs sm:text-s md:text-m lg:text-l text-start">
                        <div className="color-white">{value.name}</div>
                        <div className="color-white">{value.type}</div>
                      </div>
                    </Link>
                    <button type="button" onClick={() => updateMapCenterZoom(value.position, 15)}>
                      See Location
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
```

This should have worked, I also tried adding console.log to see if it receives the latlng and the zoom, somehow it outputs it but doesn't change the map scene

this is also a sample of the school.js

```
export const schoolData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "School 1",
        type: "Public University",
        address: "92QG+M5V, University Rd, Poblacion, Muntinlupa, Metro Manila",
        image: plmunLogo,
        link: "/dummy-website",
        coordinates:{ 
        lat:  14.389101, 
        lang: 121.025299
        }
    },
    {
        id:2,
        name: "School 2",
        type: "Private School",
        address: "Km.30 National Road, Tunasan, Muntinlupa, 1773 Metro Manila",
        image: loaiLogo,
        link: "/dummy-website2",
        coordinates: 
        {lat: 14.3730, 
        lang:121.0474}
    },
    {
        id:3,
        name: "San Beda College Alabang",
        type: "Private School",
        address: "8 Don Manolo Blvd, Cupang, Muntinlupa, 1770 Metro Manila",
        image: sbcaLogo,
        link: "/dummy-website3",
        coordinates: 
        {lat: 14.433810, 
        lang:121.026817}
    }]
export default schoolData;
```

Comment: Hi unknown user, and welcome to SO. Would you be so kind as to format and indent your code to make it easier to read?

Comment: hey I edited the code, I hope you can help me, I'm beginning to question myself in where I made something wrong

Answer (score 0):

After researching similar questions about `react-leaflet` I found that moving the map works a bit different than expected.

The `useMap` and `useMapEvents` references only work in children of the `<MapContainer />` component. Besides that, if you need a reference to the map you'll need to use the `whenCreated` property on the `MapContainer` to store a reference of the map in a state. [See example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65394661/11619647).

With this in mind, we can move the map by generating a reference to it and then call the Leaflet commands like `setView` or `flyTo` to move and zoom to the point in the map.

I've created a summarized example of how this all is implemented.

```js
import { MapContainer } from 'react-leaflet';
import { useState, useCallback } from 'react';

const MapComponent = () => {
  const [map, setMap] = useState(null);

  const updateMapCenterZoom = useCallback((newCenter, newZoom) => {
    if (map !== null) {
      map.setView(newCenter, newZoom);
    }
  }, [map]);

  return (
    <>
      <MapContainer
        preferCanvas
        center={[14.389786, 121.047566]}
        zoom={13}
        scrollWheelZoom={false}
        whenCreated={setMap}
      />

      <button type="button" onClick={() => updateMapCenterZoom([14.389786, 121.047566], 15)}>
        See Location
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default MapComponent
```

Comment: tried this, it doesn't have error, but it also don't change views, it's strange because I also added console.log just to make sure it receives the right coordinates

Comment: [https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-v-3-x-update-map-center-forked-4rkj3p?file=/src/Map.jsx:769-895] I used this link, somehow I don't get some of the logic to it and how I can apply it to mine

Comment: Hmm, alright. I'll look into it tomorrow to change the implementation.

Comment: thank you so much sir @Emiel! truly a blessing, I have been researching and trying things it doesn't seem to work, I feel stupid at this point

Comment: I also added the separate file of school.js for you not to be confused

Comment: so I've been awake for several hours, and finally done it, so what I did is create two function components, one for the SetViewOnClick second is the Map itself, using the reference I provided, I changed some of the attributes and connected it to mine and inside the school.js I created another array object which is for the center itself(I can't think of another way) and changed the filter query to not include the 1st array(schoolData[0]), so it won't throw some error since the center doesn't have a type

Comment: so for anyone wondering what is the `const [index, setIndex] = useState(0)` for, it's used for the array object, to read the what array that is, adding some key or number for your array objects make it easier and not unnecessary pointing of wrong objects, hence why in my button  `<button className='text-white' onClick={() => setIndex(school.id)}>See Location</button>`

Comment: in case of future references, when using react-leaflet, never forget to create another component which changes the view, and create another component which uses all the react-leaflet components together with the component that you created which changes view for easier editing, when using an array object always add a key, that will make navigation of objects easier for the program to search

Comment: wish they add this documentation to the react-leaflet